# Cast sub-trait pointer to super-trait pointer

Tags: pointers, rust, polymorphism

I have a struct `Foo` that implements traits `A` and `B`, where `B` is a sub-trait of `A`. I now pass a `&Foo` to function `alpha` taking a `&B`, which works as expected. However, when in function `alpha` I try to pass the pointer to function `beta` which takes a `&A`, the compiler complains that it expected trait `A`, but got trait `B`. See the following code:

```
trait A {}
trait B : A {}

struct Foo {}
impl A for Foo {}
impl B for Foo {}

fn alpha(x: &B) {
    beta(x);
}

fn beta(x: &A) {}
```

I would expect this to work, since the functions in trait `B` are a superset of the functions in `A`. So given the vtable of `B`, I should be able to construct the vtable of `A` by just picking the right function pointers. Explicit casting (`x as &A`) does not help either. Why does this not work?

Comment: TL;DR: what about when there are multiple supertraits? Implement a method on `B` that returns an `&A`.